# How to get pieces value from .torrent file

Tags: bittorrent, torrent

I am trying to build a `.torrent` file interpreter. The problem is that I can't seem  to understand how to go about interpreting the pieces value. I am aware that the pieces key contains a concatenation of the SHA-1 hashes for each piece and that SHA-1 contains 20 bytes. A result of this is that the final output should be a multiple of 20 bytes. However, after counting the bytes from the pieces value as a string or in hexadecimal form it still does not satisfy this. How should I interpret the pieces key?

Comment: Are you by chance confusing the "piece length" and "pieces" items?  The value for pieces should always be a length divisible by 20. piece length is generally some power of 2, though almost any value is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here we use bencode and bdecode, and the pieces value can get easily. I think you need to firstly read [BEP](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) for more details. What's more, you can see [this](https://www.libtorrent.org/) and use it as an example.

Comment: So from the BEP you linked, pieces are to be simply split into chunks of 20 characters and used as SHA-1 hashes if I understand this sentence correctly: "pieces maps to a string whose length is a multiple of 20. It is to be subdivided into strings of length 20, each of which is the SHA1 hash of the piece at the corresponding index."

Comment: Your understand may be not right. The whole file will be cut into many pieces, and each of the piece need to be checked if it is complete and right, so we use SHA-1 hash. And the hash we use will build a merkle tree. I think it's better to find a torrent file, open it and look at it, that may help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at a real torrent file, I found that the SHA-1 hashes had to be taken from its hexadecimal string format, but I previously thought that it was wrong because the byte length of the hash was not a multiple of 20. Turns out I forgot to add a trailing `0` to hexadecimals that were only 1 character (e.g. `a` had to be changed to `0a`)